# Keystone and openshift, getting 503 error

Tags: mongodb, openshift, keystone

Can anyone please help me install keystone.js on my openshift app?

I've pushed all my files to the remote, but get a 503 error when I browse to my page. I'm quite new to Openshift, can anyone please point me in the right direction?

I have tried changing keystone.init to:

```
var connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + dbName;

console.log(connectionString);

keystone.set('mongo', connectionString);

keystone.init({
'mongo': connectionString,
```

Still no joy, I dont get any console errors either.

Any advice much appreciated.

UPDATE: checked logs and found the following:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/5501b0c04382ecfefe0000a2/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/keystone/index.js:3:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
DEBUG: Program node keystone.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node keystone.js'
hit me
/var/lib/openshift/5501b0c04382ecfefe0000a2/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:561
});

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
```

Keystone.js

```
// Simulate config options from your production environment by
// customising the .env file in your project's root folder.

// Require keystone
var keystone = require('keystone');

// Initialise Keystone with your project's configuration.
// See http://keystonejs.com/guide/config for available options
// and documentation.

var dbName = "node";

var connectionString = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + dbName;

console.log(connectionString);

keystone.set('mongo', connectionString);

keystone.init({
    'mongo': connectionString,
    'name': 'node',
    'brand': 'node',

    'sass': 'public',
    'static': 'public',
    'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
    'views': 'templates/views',
    'view engine': 'jade',

    'auto update': true,
    'session': true,
    'auth': true,
    'user model': 'User',
    'cookie secret': '^<S0$!?a778,)~[Fx4wQvgcTw]fWq.)<s`cAJc:bExU*(L&ty9;mSV?`am:*7f.P'

});

// Load your project's Models

keystone.import('models');

// Setup common locals for your templates. The following are required for the
// bundled templates and layouts. Any runtime locals (that should be set uniquely
// for each request) should be added to ./routes/middleware.js

keystone.set('locals', {
    _: require('underscore'),
    env: keystone.get('env'),
    utils: keystone.utils,
    editable: keystone.content.editable
});

// Load your project's Routes

keystone.set('routes', require('./routes'));

// Setup common locals for your emails. The following are required by Keystone's
// default email templates, you may remove them if you're using your own.

// Configure the navigation bar in Keystone's Admin UI

keystone.set('nav', {
    'posts': ['posts', 'post-categories'],
    'enquiries': 'enquiries',
    'users': 'users'
});

// Start Keystone to connect to your database and initialise the web server

keystone.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by making sure all node modules were on the server, pushing to the repo using sourcetree kept timing out, so the modules weren't there. I FTP'd them instead.